# How to structure partial types using clean architecture?

Tags: typescript, clean-architecture

I am trying to apply Uncle Bob's [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) to a fullstack recipe application using a Node.js backend. I have some confusion on how and where to structure partial types of my domain entities.

I have a domain entity called Recipe that has a bunch of properties, some that are nested.

```
// /domain/recipe/recipeEntity.ts

export interface Recipe {
    createdAt: Date;
    id: string;
    image?: RecipeImage;
    ingredients: Ingredient[];
    title: string;
    updatedAt: Date;
  }
  
  export interface Ingredient {
    createdAt: Date;
    id: string;
    name: string;
    measurementUnit?: string;
    measurementQty?: number;
    updatedAt: Date;
  }
  
  export interface RecipeImage {
    createdAt: Date;
    id: string;
    url: string;
    updatedAt: Date;
  }
```

When the client fetches a recipe, I don't want to include all of those properties as it would clutter the data. Thus, I've created a new interface for this fetch model as follows:

```
// /domain/recipe/recipeEntity.ts

  ...

  export interface GetRecipe extends Pick<Recipe, "id" | "title">{
    image?: Pick<RecipeImage, "url">;
    ingredients: Omit<Ingredient, "createdAt" | "updatedAt">[];
  }
```

However, this feels like an overly convoluted way of doing things.

**Edit**

My thought was to use `GetRecipe` as the type for what is returned when fetching a recipe. Trying to use dependency injection, that means I have the repository definition in my domain:

```
// /domain/recipe/recipeRepository.ts

export interface RecipeRepository {
getRecipeById(id: Recipe["id"]): Promise<GetRecipe | null>;
}
```

which passes through a getRecipeByIdUseCase to recipeRepositoryImplementation where the DB query is specified using graphQL.

```
// /data/recipeRepositoryImpl.ts
...
const getRecipeById = async (id: Recipe["id"]):Promise<GetRecipe> => (
  await getRecipeQuery(id);
)
```

The data will then be used in the client.

1. Have you got any recommendations for improvements for constructing such partial types to limit what's being fetched from the client?
2. Where would a potential `GetRecipe` interface be defined within the Clean Architecture? In the domain? Among the Interface Adapters?

Comment: Welcome Dave
Could you please be more specific what the intent of the `GetRecipe` interface is? Where is it used?

Comment: @Andreas, kindly see my edit. The intention is to use `GetRecipe` at the repository definition in the domain as well as in the outer circles, e.g., for the client

Comment: It looks like `GetRecipe` is not an entity but some response model, it should not be coupled to the entity. The fact they look so similar is accidental, they may diverge more over time and defining one in terms of the other will be more and more contrived. You can even consider that the place where `GetRecipe` is used has a bounded context where being a `Recipe` means something sligthly different from what it means in other parts of the system

Comment: @DaveWeng I see, so the `GetRecipe` type is part of an interface, while the other types `Recipe`, `Ingredient` and `RecipeImage` describe what is actually stored internally, e.g. in the DB? If so, I would concur with @geoffrey and keep the types separate. This way the implementation can change while the interface stays the same.

Comment: I would add that in the clean architecture you don't couple the entity with the DB either. The persistence mechanism is merely a plugin and has different constraints than the critical business rules and the critical business data. For example it may need to be structured a certain way for performance. The entity should not have to know about that, especially given they are considered application independent in the clean architecture.

Comment: @geoffrey I agree with your arguments. Would it then be reasonable to define the getRecipe declaration in the domain recipeRepository as a generic that can be set from the outer layers as follows? 

`export interface RecipeRepository {
getRecipeById<T>(id: Recipe["id"]): Promise<T>;
}`